# How can I activate 'Group Insights' on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I manage more than one Facebook Group and I noticed that not all of them show the feature "Group Insights".

Group 1

[image: example with Group Insights]

Group 2

[image: example without Group Insights]

Question: How can I activate this feature?

Comment: I was looking exactly for this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook automatically enables "Group Insight" feature as soon as you have 250 members on your community.

For further information check out [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/312362745877176) post on Facebook's documentation.